# How to filter pandas groupby object based on groupby.groups.keys()

Tags: python-3.x, filter, pandas-groupby, concatenation

I have pandas dataframes df1 and df2

```
df1:
     City  Pop Homes Other
0  City_1  100     1     0
1  City_1  100     2     6
2  City_1  100     2     2
3  City_1  100     3     9
4  City_1  200     1     6
5  City_1  200     2     6
6  City_1  200     3     7
7  City_1  300     1     0

df2:
     City  Pop Homes Other
0  City_1  100     1     0
1  City_1  100     2     6
2  City_1  100     2     2
3  City_1  100     8     9
4  City_1  200     1     6
5  City_1  200     2     6
6  City_1  800     3     7
7  City_1  800     8     0
```

And I want to create df3 that has the same columns as df1 and df2, but only includes rows where the paired Pop and Homes values are the same.

```
df3:
     City  Pop Homes Other
0  City_1  100     1     0
1  City_1  100     2     6
2  City_1  100     2     2
4  City_1  200     1     6
5  City_1  200     2     6
```

To get the pairs in df1 and df2, I've done:

```
df1_string = """
City_1      100      1     0
City_1      100      2     6
City_1      100      2     2
City_1      100      3     9
City_1      200      1     6
City_1      200      2     6
City_1      200      3     7
City_1      300      1     0"""

df2_string = """
City_1      100      1     0
City_1      100      2     6
City_1      100      2     2
City_1      100      8     9
City_1      200      1     6
City_1      200      2     6
City_1      800      3     7
City_1      800      8     0"""

df1 = pd.DataFrame([x.split() for x in df1_string.split('\n')], columns=['City', 'Pop', 'Homes', 'Other'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([x.split() for x in df2_string.split('\n')], columns=['City', 'Pop', 'Homes', 'Other'])

df1_keys = [x for x in df1.groupby(['Pop', 'Homes']).groups.keys()]
df2_keys = [x for x in df2.groupby(['Pop', 'Homes']).groups.keys()]

print(df1_keys)
[('100', '1'), ('100', '2'), ('100', '3'), ('200', '1'), ('200', '2'), ('200', '3'), ('300', '1')]
print(df2_keys)
[('100', '1'), ('100', '2'), ('100', '8'), ('200', '1'), ('200', '2'), ('800', '3'), ('800', '8')]
```

But I don't know how to filter df1 from here. I thought it would be something like this:

```
df1 = df1[df1.groupby(['Pop', 'Homes']).groups.keys().isin(df2.groupby(['Pop', 'Homes']).groups.keys())]
```

But that doesn't work.

I should also mention, df1 and df2 are not always the same length.

**SOLUTION**

```
df1.set_index(['Pop', 'Homes'], inplace=True)
df2.set_index(['Pop', 'Homes'], inplace=True)

df1 = df1[df2.index.isin(df1.index)]

df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the indices as Pop and Home generates the value 'pairs' and using isin() applies the filter needed:

```
df1.set_index(['Pop', 'Homes'], inplace=True)
df2.set_index(['Pop', 'Homes'], inplace=True)

df1 = df1[df2.index.isin(df1.index)]

df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
print(df1)
```